# Algorithm for calculating all boxes selected by a rectangular selection

Tags: algorithm

Supposed you've got a large amount of boxes drawn, and the user can draw a rectangular area over them.

While I'll be implementing it inside a browser, let's abstract it away and say we've got the coordinates of every point of every rectangle.

What are the most efficient data structures and algorithms here, given I want to check which boxes `a) intersect` `b) are contained by` the selection?

My current idea is to:

- Sort all boxes by `x`
- Via binsearch, check which boxes overlap x-wise with the selection area, then, for every x-wise overlapping box, check if they align y-wise as well.

or

- Sort all boxes by `x` and `y`, each in separate array
- Via binsearch, first find all x-overlapping boxes, then all y-overlapping boxes, then check which boxes are in both sets,

... though I'm pretty sure there's some well-known algorithm for such a problem.

Comment: Note that there is a difference between: "I have a large number of boxes, plus a rectangular area; what is the most efficient way to calculate which boxes are selected?" and "I have a large number of boxes, and I want to prepare a data structure to most efficiently find which boxes are selected when in the future, I get rectangular areas".

Comment: For instance, testing out each box one by one is linear in the number of boxes; whereas sorting the boxes takes `n log n` operations where `n` is the number of boxes; so while sorting might be efficient in the long run (if you only sort once, then are presented repeatedly with rectangular areas), it is actually less efficient than a naive algorithm if you want an immediate result with just one rectangular area.

Comment: Indeed, I meant the second: a data structure that allows for quick searches. Gonna add it to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose by *selected* via some rectangle you mean either *intersects* some rectangle or *is contained* in some rectangle. If the "drawn boxes" are of fixed position, one approach which comes to mind is [binary space partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning). Roughly speaking, an (ideally balanced) binary space partition tree could be generated for the "drawn boxes". If the selection rectangle is positioned, the positions of its corners would be matched against the binary space partition tree, and large halfspaces could be excluded from explicit checking for intersection.